# NodeList to list box display

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I am currently having a problem putting the results of a xmlnodelist into a normal list box with the below code.

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(textBox1.Text);

var node = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("pdml/packet/proto/field[@name='ip.src']/@show");
list.Items.Add(node);
```

To my understanding the SelectNodes will take all nodes with that XPath name and put it into a list. When I add these to a standard list box I see this displayed:

```
System.Xml.XPathNodeList
```

For reference, this specific xml looks as so (it is a portion of a much larger  section):

```
 <pdml>
 <packet>
 <proto>
 <field name="ip.src" showname="Source: 192.168.1.204 (192.168.1.204)" size="4" pos="26" show="192.168.1.204" value="c0a801cc"/>
 </proto>
 </packet>
 </pdml>
```

How do I convert this into what is contained in the NodeList?

Further help:
Also how could I work with the data contained in the NodeList? e.g. can I set it as a unique identifier and assign other node data to it.

Thanks, 
Tom

Comment: You want to get all data from each "field" to list?

Comment: The data I want to get out is the show: 192.168.1.204. but from every field in the xml doc with that XPath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`node` contains collection of `XmlAttribute`. I believe you meant to add `Value` of each attribute to `list.Items` :

```
foreach (XmlAttribute attribute in node)
{
    list.Items.Add(attribute.Value);
}
```

or possibly using `AddRange()` method and LINQ to add all attributes value at once :

```
list.Items.AddRange(from XmlAttribute attribute in node select attribute.Value);
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise I had to do that. Would up vote as well but not enough rep haha.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is option, but you have to create list "shows":

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("your xml file");
foreach (var elem in xDoc.Document.Descendants("field[@name='ip.src']"))
{
    shows.Add(elem.Attribute("show").Value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, this would probably work in the case of the packet sample above but the complete version has about 40 or 50 'fields' a lot of which also contain 'show' attributes. Thanks again for the quick reply.

Comment: It would work for all elem "field" in this xml ;) not only one

Comment: Sorry, meant to say that these other 'fields' and 'shows' contain information about different data that is not needed.

Comment: You can add .Contains() method to get only with ip.src ;)

Comment: try now if you want to ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add each item to the list not a collection as one item in the list. As list has only one item of type **XmlNodeList** it call **ToString** on this object and it result into **System.Xml.XPathNodeList** message. You should use `list.Items.AddRange` if it exist (it is not clear what UI framework you are using) or you should iterate the XmlNodeList collection:

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(textBox1.Text);

var nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("pdml/packet/proto/field[@name='ip.src']/@show");
foreach(var node in nodes)
    list.Items.Add(node);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. When I put in the above code it returns: System.Xml.XMLAttribute.
Still no data.

Comment: As stated in my answer, instead of the `XmlAttribute` it self it's `Value` should've been added to `Items` : `list.Items.Add(node.Value)`